# Macbook does not show USB port to my Arduino Portenta H7

Tags: arduino, usb, port, stm32

I recently got an Arduino board (Portenta H7). I would like to load programs with the arduino ide on the controller, which has worked well so far. Since this morning it no longer works, because the usb port is no longer recognized. I have already changed the cable and also reinstalled the drivers.
When i connect the board to the Mac the previously loaded program is played.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this ?

thank you very much.

Comment: If you updated to MacOS Big Sur, some users reported virtual serial port problems after update.

Comment: The MacBook is at macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think I found the solution working for me.

I use D-link USB-C to USB HMI and Ethernet hub, connect normal USB to USB-C wire and it connected to the MacBook and Arduino IDE is able to program it :-)

I think with other USB hub will also work.

Jacob